# how to add target blank in angularjs script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I'm a little confused. I have to add a target="_blank" to my a. The problem is that tag a has an appeal to a script in angular. I don't know this js framework. I tried to find in documentation some kinda solutions but still doesn't work. Maybe any hints?

pug.js

```
li(
     ng-click="visitElement"
     ng-attr-target="_blank"
   )
   a visit element
```

angular.js

```
    $scope.visitElement = (res) -> {
      $location.url "/orgs"
    }
```

So I was wondered what can I do more to add this atrr to my href.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native HTML:

```
li
  a(href='http://google.com', target='_blank') visit element
```